# Can I SLI a 8800GTX and a 9600GT?

Tags: gpu, nvidia-geforce, sli

I'm not sure how much more I need to elaborate, but anyway I have two graphics cards: one 8800GTX and one 9600GT. Can I SLI them together?

Is there an online tool that tells you what goes together?

Or do they always have to be the same model?

As far as I can garner they can be different manufacturers, but not sure about the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No that will not work, the GPU must be the same.

From their [FAQ](http://www.slizone.com/page/slizone_faq.html#c16):

> **Can I mix and match graphics cards that have different GPUs?**
>  No.
>   For example, an XXXGT cannot be paired
>   with a XXXGTX in an SLI configuration.